# How can self taught mathematicians contribute to the progression of mathematics?

Tags: mathematics, independent-researcher

I am a self taught engineer and mathematician with 20+ years of product engineering experience. I have various patents and have sat on global standards committees--mostly for occupant safety systems. I work today as an in-house consultant.  I've been able to contribute to the safety of drivers all over the world and yet when it comes to mathematics I haven't found a way to participate.

I have shared some of my ideas with professors and others in my field with masters and doctorate degrees with a positive reception and have used my math skills to great success in solving a wide range of problems. I have methods and ideas that I feel can help Americans appreciate mathematics beyond the scope of the classroom but I keep hitting the '...you must have a PhD (from an accredited college), wall'. Is there a way for people like me to contribute?

Comment: Why do you want to contribute to the progression of mathematics in America, _only_?

Comment: Who is telling you  that '...you must have a PhD'? I have not heard of any serious publication medium that requires a degree to publish in.

Comment: Where exactly are you running into these walls? Publishing? Conferences? Applying for adjunct or lecturer positions? Applying for research grants?

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you mean by "contribute."  Do you want to do research?  Or are your goals popularization and education?  "appreciate math beyond the scope of the classroom" sounds like the latter.  Do you want to write papers?  What kind of mathematics?  Do you want to serve on secondary education curriculum committees?  As currently phrased your question is too vague to answer.

Comment: Wow. I thank you all for the quick reply. By contribute I mean mathematical research. I do research for the modeling of mechanical assemblies and risk associated with the interfaces between them. This is typically done by what's called Failure Mode and Effects Analysis or DFMEA.

Comment: Consider these articles by Richard Lipton: https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2010/07/01/can-amateurs-solve-pnp/, https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2010/07/11/proving-a-proof-is-a-proof/

Comment: So who's stopping you from doing research?

Comment: I've edited the question to be less negative.  Perhaps it's already been answered, though.

Comment: I think we need you to further clarify what you are trying to do, and who is stopping you. Are you having trouble getting collaborators? Getting papers published? Getting financial support for your research? Getting a job that involves doing research in mathematics? What are you trying to do, exactly? If we know the specifics, we can probably reopen the question and offer a specific answer.

Comment: You may also be interested in browsing the other questions tagged [tag:independent-researcher], and in particular those that are [also tagged mathematics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independent-researcher+mathematics)

Comment: No one is stopping me from doing research. The issue is trying to get the research out there with the aims of giving engineers, or anyone else for that matter, methods of decision making that leads to better products. In the my field the trend is for engineers to be more administrative than creative. Many of my colleagues know my work but unless I have masters or PhD my recommendations or solutions remain a secret. I cannot share the solutions but I can share the methods I used to get to the solutions which can help engineers and others in the classroom setting and beyond.

Comment: I must have misunderstood something, because it sounds to me like you're asking "why can't I publish engineering research in math journals" to which the answer is because you publish engineering research in engineering journals.  Engineers aren't typically reading math journals, so doing math research is not a great way to reach them.

Comment: @CecilBrown From your comments, I understood you want to teach your colleagues the mathematical methods you used successfully in your work, but they won't listen to you because you have no PhD, yet. Is that correct?

Comment: You may contribute by writing an paper solving an open mathematical problem, submitting it to a mathematical journal, and getting it published. That's the most standard, typical mathematical process of getting acceptance in the community. After you are done with your first publication, look what do you want to do next. Otherwise, I see no chance.

Comment: The field of engineering is based upon math. This is especially true in electrical and mechanical engineering. Engineering research is mostly confined to materials. Tools such as groups, graphs, calculus, probability and statistics are the mathematical tools that engineers used to make conclusions about a design, reliability and so on. All of these tools are in the realm of applied math at time, abstract algebra. So mathematics is the language between industries and disciplines.

Comment: "The issue is trying to get the research out there" - What have you tried to do, to get your research "out there"? It's still not clear what you are trying to do, and why you aren't able to do it. Are you trying to publish your research in a journal, and if so, what kind? Are you trying to engage others in a less formal way e.g. by writing a blog, and if so, who are you trying to engage? It's not clear what kind of audience you are trying to reach, and what you have tried to do to reach that audience.

Comment: I just realized something. When I invent something I get a patent and that patent goes out into the patent universe for all to see. I see now that I am mixing two processes--journals are for a specific audience and patents are for a global industry. I thank you all for your comments because now I see the error in my logic. Through my research on congruence I found the relation: |x| = tan( acos( cos( atan(x) ) ) ), which returns the unsigned value of any real x. How would I go about getting ideas like this in the hands of an organization that can put it in the mathematics universe?

Comment: "So mathematics is the language between industries and disciplines." But mathematics research does not resemble anything like engineering research. Even suggesting that it does will make you sound like a quack. Have you read the papers in the journals you are submitting to? Notably " I found the relation: |x| = tan( acos( cos( atan(x) ) ) ), which returns the unsigned value of any real x" is trivial for teaching and could be a blog post (or an undergrad homework assignment to prove), but definitely not a paper. Read the journals you want to submit to, and match the style. Or just blog.

Comment: Again I thank you all for the discussion. Your comments are helping to explain much of the correspondence I've had over the years. I have done a lot of engineering research where the outcome was an equation or algorithm for the purpose of predicting the behavior of various products and design. If I understand your comment correctly, the result of mathematical research should be within and non-trivial to the domain being researched. So although my research results in some mathematical tool, it is not considered mathematical research because the domain is engineering. Is this correct?

Comment: @CecilBrown: No, that's not really accurate. There is much active research in the area of _applied mathematics_, which is a sort of crossover between math and other STEM fields, including engineering. The more important issue is that the research to be published in mathematical journals needs to be considered "non-trivial." Something that could appear in a homework problem or short research project doesn't meet that qualification.

Comment: To consider voting to reopen this, I'd need to see the relevant information from the comments edited into the main question.

Comment: This post started out rough for me, mainly due to frustrating world of engineering, but this has helped me sort things out quite a bit. I have a way to use knot theory for mechanical assemblies and the journal guys pretty much said what you guys are saying here. I will seriously consider the blog option (thanks ff524 and Chris Rackauckas). But, since I am not part of Academia, is this forum the right place to get advice on the contents of my blog posts to make sure they are readable for academics and engineers alike? Or would I have to consult a local university?

Comment: @CecilBrown: We can't really help advise you on the contents of your blog on this forum directly. You could do that in chat [where these comments will shortly be moved], but not on the direct forum board.